# Kohana validation client-side ajax

Tags: ajax, validation, kohana

i've been working on a validation script for client-side, that uses built-in Kohana validation, trying to do it in a way that works both client and server sides. So far i made the server side work, but i need some help improving my javascript (My javascript knowlodgement ain't that good) and finish implementing it. (Currently it works for inputs and textareas).

A random controller:

```
    // ...
    $errors = array();

    if ($this->request->method() == 'POST')
    {
        // Post to validate/look and get the decoded array
        $validate = Request::factory('validate/look')->post($this->request->post())->execute()->body();
        $errors = json_decode($validate, TRUE);

        // Empty array, Validation OK
        if ($errors === array())
        {
            // anything u want here
        }
    }
```

Now, the Validation controller (which will be called from any controller, or via ajax):

```
class Controller_Validate extends Controller {

public function action_look()
{
    //$user = $this->user->loader() ? $this->user : NULL;

    //Validation
    $valid = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
        ->rules('name', array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('min_length', array(':value', 10)),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 80)),
            array('regex', array(':value', '/^[\pL\pN ]++$/uD')),
            array(array($this, 'check_name')),
        ))
        ->rules('description', array(
            array('not_empty'),
        ))
        ->rule('look_tags', array($this, 'check_tags'))
    ;

    $valid->check();

    // Only get messages for the posted fields
    $resp = array_intersect_key($valid->errors('uploadlook'), $this->request->post());

    $this->response->body(json_encode($resp));
}
}
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('.validate').find('input,textarea').blur(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/comunidad/validate/look',
        data: name + '=' + value,
        success: function(e){
            e = JSON.parse(e);
            if(e.length !== 0) {
                var msg = e[name];
                var error = '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
                if (element.next().length === 0)    element.after(error);
                else                                element.next().replaceWith(error);
            } else {
                if (element.next().length) element.next().remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

I need some feedback and little help completing the javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

Some feedback on the code: 
The validation code shoud be put in a helper and should just return an array. Then you should have an AJAX-controller that uses the helper and outputs JSON. The serverside check should only use the helper.
That would be much cleaner and the json encode/decode on the server side is pretty ugly when you can just return an array.

What is wrong with the javascript?